# getting 404 error when creating new route, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

it appears that when I created a new route, I receive the 404 error when trying to access the url, which is funny,. because all of my other routes are working just fine.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

$ads_controller = 'App\Http\Controllers\AdsController@';

$favorites_controller = 'App\Http\Controllers\FavoritesController@';

Route::get('/', $ads_controller.'index')->name('index');

Route::get('/ads/favorites', $favorites_controller.'index');


Route::get('/ads/create', $ads_controller.'create')->name('ads.create');

Route::post('/', $ads_controller.'store')->name('ads.store');

Route::get('/ads/{id}', $ads_controller.'show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');;

Route::get('/ads/{id}/edit', $ads_controller.'edit')->where('id', '[0-9]+');;

Route::put('/ads/{id}', $ads_controller.'update')->where('id', '[0-9]+');;

Route::delete('/ads/{id}', $ads_controller.'destroy')->where('id', '[0-9]+');;

Route::get('/ajax/popupimgs', $ads_controller.'get_images');


Auth::routes([
    'register' => true,
]);
```

The one that is NOT working when I am visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/ads/favorites is:

```
$favorites_controller = 'App\Http\Controllers\FavoritesController@';
Route::get('/ads/favorites', $favorites_controller.'index');
```

The controller looks like so:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Favorites;
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as DebugBar;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FavoritesController extends Controller
{
    // favorites page
    public function index()
    {
        return view('ads.favorites');
    }
}
```

that what i get:
[image]

Comment: Did you clear/rebuild the route cache? `php artisan route:cache` ?

Comment: sometimes I have to stop and restart my local env. It is most likely a cache issue locally.

Comment: you can have a look at the available routes through artisan with `php artisan route:list`, then you can see the name for each single route

Answer (score 0):

For laravel 8
You might wanna do

```
Route::get('ads/favorites', [App\Http\Controllers\FavoritesController::class, 'index']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#view-routes

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command for rebuild the route cache

```
php artisan route:cache
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching

Answer (score 0):

The routes order MATTERS.
Move your first route

```
Route::get('/', $ads_controller.'index')->name('index');
```

after the route

```
Route::get('/ads/favorites', $favorites_controller.'index');
```

What's happening here is that your first route is catching all GET requests at first.

Try with this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

$ads_controller = 'App\Http\Controllers\AdsController@';

$favorites_controller = 'App\Http\Controllers\FavoritesController@';

Route::get('/ads/favorites', $favorites_controller.'index');

Route::get('/ads/create', $ads_controller.'create')->name('ads.create');

Route::post('/', $ads_controller.'store')->name('ads.store');

Route::get('/ads/{id}', $ads_controller.'show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');;

Route::get('/ads/{id}/edit', $ads_controller.'edit')->where('id', '[0-9]+');;

Route::put('/ads/{id}', $ads_controller.'update')->where('id', '[0-9]+');;

Route::delete('/ads/{id}', $ads_controller.'destroy')->where('id', '[0-9]+');;

Route::get('/ajax/popupimgs', $ads_controller.'get_images');

Route::get('/', $ads_controller.'index')->name('index');


Auth::routes([
    'register' => true,
]);
```